# Java ThreadPool limit maximum thread ever created

Tags: java, multithreading, matrix-multiplication, java-threads

I am trying to write a Java multithreaded program performing a multiplication on 2 matrices given as a file and using a **limited total of threads** used.

For example if I set a number of thread at 16 I want my threadpool to be able to reuse those 16 threads until all the tasks are done.

However I end up with a larger execution time for a larger number of threads and I am having a hard time trying to understand why.

**Runnable:**

```
class Task implements Runnable
{
    int _row = 0;
    int _col = 0;

    public Task(int row, int col)
    {
        _row = row;
        _col = col;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Application.multiply(_row, _col);
    }
}
```

**Application:**

```
public class Application
{
    private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    private static int _A[][];
    private static int _B[][];
    private static int _C[][];

    public static void main(final String [] args) throws InterruptedException
    {                
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(16);
        ThreadPoolExecutor pool = (ThreadPoolExecutor) executor;

        _A = readMatrix();
        _B = readMatrix();
        _C = new int[_A.length][_B[0].length];

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int x = 0; x < _C.length; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < _C[0].length; y++)
            {
                executor.execute(new Task(x, y));
            }
        }
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        executor.shutdown();
        executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.HOURS);

        System.out.printf("Calculation Time: %d ms\n" , endTime - startTime);
   }

    public static void multMatrix(int row, int col)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < _B.length; i++)
        {
            sum += _A[row][i] * _B[i][col];
        }
        _C[row][col] = sum;
    }

    ...
}
```

The matrix calculations and workload sharing seems correct so it might come from a bad use of ThreadPool

Comment: Note that usually, the optimal number of threads to create (ie limit your thread pool with) is the amount of cores in your CPU: http://codeidol.com/java/java-concurrency/Applying-Thread-Pools/Sizing-Thread-Pools/

Comment: How many threads your CPU can execute ?

Comment: Multiple threads are practically useful when you have multiple processors (cores) to handle them.

Comment: I have 8 available processors. I am not trying to find the optimal number of threads but really just run the program with the specified number and make use of those threads to execute all tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context switching takes time. 
If you have 8 cores and you are executing 8 threads they all can work simultaneously and as soon as one finishes it will be reused. 
On the other hand if you have 16 threads for 8 cores each thread will compete for the processor time and scheduler will switch those threads and your time would increase to - Execution time + Context swithcing.

The more the threads the more the context switching and hence the time increases.

Comment: Never heard of context switching before but I do understand now. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Those threads are already being reused to execute the tasks, that's the expected behaviour of ThreadPoolExecutor.

http://www.codejava.net/java-core/concurrency/java-concurrency-understanding-thread-pool-and-executors
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

You're getting a higher computation time as you increase the name of threads because the time needed to create them is greater than the improvement of performance that the concurrency gives at the execution of that -relative short- tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification I understand

Answer (score 0):

**Use submit instead of execute**

Make a list of returned `Future`s so that you can wait for them.

```
List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

futures.add(executor.submit(new Task(x, y)));
```

Then just wait for these futures to complete.

Comment: Tried this already but it doesn't change my execution time. It still takesmore time with more threads.